# Unable to install mysql

Tags: mysql, windows

Whenever I try to install mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.17.0, I receive the following error :

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue.

If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.

The Process cannot access the file

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Product Cache\mysql-connector-c++ 1.1.7-winx64.msi.temp
```

Below are the details of the error:

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL
>   Installer for Windows\Product
>   Cache\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.7-winx64.msi.temp' because it is being
>   used by another process.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   WexInstaller.Core.DownloadManager.DownloadFileCompleted(Object sender,
>   AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadFileCompleted(AsyncCompletedEventArgs
>   e)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- MySQLInstaller
>       Assembly Version: 1.4.18.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.4.18.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MySQL/MySQL%20Installer%20for%20Windows/MySQLInstaller.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Core
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- MySQLInstaller.Core
>       Assembly Version: 1.4.18.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.4.18.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MySQL/MySQL%20Installer%20for%20Windows/MySQLInstaller.Core.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- WindowsBase
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.GeneratedCode
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.GeneratedCode
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.GeneratedCode
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.GeneratedCode
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.GeneratedCode
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Accessibility
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Data
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1636.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- StandardPlugins
>       Assembly Version: 1.4.18.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.4.18.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/MySQL/MySQL%20Installer%20for%20Windows/StandardPlugins.DLL
>   ---------------------------------------- System.ServiceProcess
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceProcess/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.GeneratedCode
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Am I missing something? Someone help me please

Comment: Are all your MSVC runtimes up to date

Comment: I'm sure they are updated

Comment: And you have them all including the new universal thingamijig

Comment: Please what is the "univerasal thingamijig"?